# A small clarification about quotient spaces

Tags: general-topology

A surjective map $\ P\ : X\rightarrow Y$ is said to be generating a quotient topology if any $U$ is open in $Y$ if and only if $\ p^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$. Now as such by the definition of homeomorphism $P $ is a homeomorphism. 
Is it so that all the quotient maps are homeomorphisms and if we can transfer one set into another by an equivalence relation,i.e., obtain the quotient space of a set then does it mean that the set and its quotient space are homeomorphic ?

Answer (score 4):

$P$ is not a homeomorphism. The whole point is that $P$ is generally not bijective, hence not a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

It's in fact true that $P$ is a bijective quotient map if and only if $P$ is a homeomorphism, but any non-injective quotient map $P$ is not a homeomorphism.

An easy counterexample is to define a relation $\sim$ on $\Bbb{R}$ by $a\sim b$ if and only if $a\cdot b\not=0$. Then, there are only two equivalence classes, namely $[1]$ and $[0]$. Furthermore, let $X:=\Bbb{R}/\sim=\{[0],[1]\}$ and assign the topology on $X$ by $\{X,\emptyset,\{[1]\}\}$. Then, the natural map $p:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow X$ is a quotient map, but is not a homeomorphism as $X$ and $\Bbb{R}$ have different cardinalities.