# Some subtle points about Homeomorphisms and quotient maps

Tags: general-topology

Let us consider two spaces $\ X$ and $\ Y$. Let us say that there is a quotient map $\ F $ defined from $\ X $ to $\ Y $.
Now by the definition of quotient map , $\ F $ is surjective , as such for every $\ y$ $\ \epsilon$$\ Y$, there must exist atleast one $\ x$ $\ \epsilon$$\ X$ such that $\ F(x)$ =$\ y$  and a set $\ U $ in $\ Y $ is open if and only if $\ F^-1$($\ U$) is open in $\ X$.
Let us consider a case where for two sets $\ P$ and $\ Q$ in $\ X $ , a particular set $\ R $ in  $\ Y $ be  related as $\ R $= $\ F(P)$=$\ F(Q)$ . Now let us suppose that $\ P $ is open  but $\ Q$ isn't . So, would we consider $\ R$ open or not? What shall be considered as $\ F^-1(R) $, $\ P$$\ \cup$$\ Q$ or only $\ P $ ? Is this a forbidden case ?

Now suppose that in the above case both $\ P $ and $\ Q $ are open . Let $\ G$ be the inverse of $\ F$ .
Now for every open set $\ V$ in $\ Y $ , $\ F^-1(V)$ is open in X . Let $\ U $ be $\ F^-1(V)$ , then $\ G^-1$$\ (U)$ is $\ V$ ,which is open in $\ Y$ and as such $\ G$ is also continuous . Hence , $\ F$ is a homeomorphism .
So , why isn't a quotient map a homeomorphism ? One of the answers in my last question said that for a homeomorphism one needs to have the same cardinality of the set of open sets . Now coming back to the sets $\ P $ and $\ Q$ , , in the case when both $\ P $ and $\ Q $ are open , if we choose all the three $\ P $ , $\ Q$ and $\ P$ $\ \cup$$\ Q$ as the inverse of $\ R$ , then we won;t have the same number of open sets  in both the domain and range and even if we choose only one of them we won't be having the same cardinality .
The definition of homeomorphism that I know of is a function $\ F$ :$\ X$$\ \to$ $\ Y$ where $\ X$ and $\ Y $ are topological spaces and both $\ F$ and $\ F^-1$ are continuous mappings . How can we conclude the existence of Bijection between the sets of open sets from this definition ?

Comment: This question has the same incorrect assumption as your previous question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803467/a-small-clarification-about-quotient-spaces, namely, quotient maps need not be one-to-one. And therefore they need not have inverses. So the inverse of $F$ need not exist.

Answer (score 1):

If for *subsets* of $X$ we have $F[P] = F[Q] = R$, then we cannot say anything about $R$, because $F^{-1}[R] = \{x \in X: F(x) \in R \}$, and so $P \cup Q \subseteq F^{-1}[R]$ and we have no info on whether this is equality or whether $P \cup Q$ is open etc.

$G$ does not exist (except when $F$ is 1-1, which is a trivial case).

A subset $U \subseteq Y$ is open iff $F^{-1}[U] := \{x \in X: F(x) \in U \}$ is open. This does not mean that $F$ has an inverse, it's just a convenient notation for all preimages of members of $U$. There is no choice involved, it;s the set of **all** $x$ that map into $U$ under $F$.

Comment: OK,so only bijective mas can be homeomoprhic,right ?

Comment: @jednadve Yes, a quotient map is a homeomorphism iff it is injective.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a quotient map $F : X \to Y$ does not tell you about **arbitrary** open subsets of $X$; it only tells you about **saturated** open subsets of $X$.

A subset $A \subset X$ is saturated if $A = F^{-1}(F(A))$. Equivalently, $A$ is saturated if for all $x,y \in X$, if $x \in A$ and $F(x)=F(y)$ then $y \in A$.

What the definition of quotient map tells you is that for every saturated subset $A \subset X$, $A$ is open in $X$ if and only if $F(A)$ is open in $Y$.

So let us go to the first question you asked: given $P,Q \subset X$ and $R=F(P)=F(Q) \subset Y$, what if $P$ is open and $Q$ isn't? What can you say about $R$? In general you can say nothing about $R$. Different examples show that $R$ can be open, or closed, or both, or neither.

For an example with $R$ closed but not open, take $X=\big(\mathbb{R} \times 0\big) \cup \big([0,1] \times 1\big)$, $Y=\mathbb{R}$, $F(y,t)=y$, $P=[0,1] \times 1$, and $Q=[0,1] \times 0$, and $R = [0,1]$.

For an example wth $R$ open but not closed, take $X = \big(\mathbb{R} \times 0\big) \cup \big((0,1) \times 1\big)$, $Y = \mathbb{R}$, $F(y,t)=y$, $P=(0,1) \times 1$, $Q = (0,1) \times 0$, and $R=(0,1)$.

Notice that in these examples, neither $P$ nor $Q$ are saturated; this is what I kept in mind to construct the examples.

Comment: OK,so only bijective mas can be homeomoprhic,right ?

Comment: That is corrrect, bijection is part of the definition of homeomorphism.